# Uninstalling Paid Software with Key Code

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, adobe-photoshop, uninstall

I have never uninstalled paid software (that uses a long Activation code) before in order to use it on another computer, but that's what I want to do now.

I need to do it with Photoshop (from my old PC to my new one) and with MS Office (from my old laptop to my new one).

But what I don't understand is: How do these companies know that I have uninstalled it from the first computer?

Could they not just think I'm trying to have the software on several PCs?

(I know you're allowed MS Office on up to 3 devices, but it will be 3 in total when sorted).

I just want to uninstall everything properly, so I don't get in trouble or have any hassle.

Is the process straightforward?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention which version of the software you are using, but for recent versions the following is generic advice that will work:

In photoshop, go to the Help menu, then click deactivate. That tells Adobe you're no longer using this computer. Then uninstall correctly through the product uninstaller, typically found on the start menu. When you install on your other computer, the product registration will reactivate your license.

In MS Office, you can just uninstall using the uninstaller and the product takes care of the deactivation itself. ~http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927921